# Converting Bitmap to WriteableBitmap in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using c # in my application. I have  convert Bitmap to WritableBitmap directly.
I don't want to convert bitmap to other other format.

```
    pdftron.PDF.PDFDraw draw = new pdftron.PDF.PDFDraw();
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiBitmap = draw.GetBitmap(_pdfDoc.GetPage(page)))
        {

            // System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(target);
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(gdiBitmap))
            {
                System.Drawing.Color customColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(50, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                System.Drawing.SolidBrush shadowBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(customColor);
                g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle[] { rectangle });
            }
}
```

Now I have to convert It in WritableBitmap.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to create `BitmapSource` from your `Bitmap`, and then you can create `WriteableBitmap` from it.

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource bitmapSource =
  System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
  gdiBitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);
```